# Passing Bamboo Artifacts from One Project to Another

Tags: bamboo

The current way we have our product set up is that there is a full project in Bamboo that handles just the "Shipping". This project checks everything out from git and runs the unit tests and then copies it to a pre-QA server.

We now have a need for some CI testing on the pre-QA server that will run some more unit tests and other automated tests (primarily selenium and java stuff). Administrators want this to be defined as a separate project.

So with this comes the question: How do I pass the artifact from the original project to this new project in Bamboo? This is important, because we are generating the build number that we use in QA in the Shipping project, but the reporting for the QA CI testing (second project) needs to also report which build number it performed the tests on.

Also, how would I trigger the second project in Bamboo? My very brief understanding of Bamboo is that Plans can only be dependent on other plans in the same project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: This is now possible since Bamboo 5. Please check this link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Sharing+artifacts

> How do I pass the artifact from the original project to this new
>   project in Bamboo?

Unfortunately you can't, at least until this issue gets solved: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-10573

What you can do is to share artifacts from one job to the other (within the same plan). If you must use different plans then you can:

- copy your artifacts in a shared location and then grab it in the other plan (recommended)
- If you are using maven, you can execute mvn deploy to "publish" the last snapshot and then grab it, also with maven, in the QA plan. You have a potential race condition here (other developers executing the same command), so it's better to be careful.